# String without quotes within a string?

Tags: python, string, loops, text-files

I'm trying to write text to file, but I have other text I need to include besides the targeted string. When I'm looping over the targeted strings it is printed with quotes as the quotes are needed for other text. 
How to remove quotes from a string that I'm inserting each loop?

```
list=['random', 'stuff', 1]
with open(textfile, 'a') as txtfile:
    for item in list:
        print("""Need to have stuff before %a and after each loop string"""  
        %item, file=txtfile)
```

**Output:** Need to have stuff before 'random' and after each loop string.
**Desired output:**  Need to have stuff before random and after each loop string.

Comment: change %a to %s

Comment: works like a charm. The only part of my code I did not vary for more options. Many thanks for the quick, precise answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> li=['random', 'stuff', 1]
>>> for item in li:
...    print("before {} after".format(item))
... 
before random after
before stuff after
before 1 after
```

Or you can use `%s` with the `%` operator:

```
>>> for item in li:
...    print("before %s after" % item)
... 
before random after
before stuff after
before 1 after
```

(And don't call a list `list` or you will overwrite the Python function of the same name...)

Comment: Thank you. Bonus karma points for the added pointer on the list naming.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right except that when you need to use `%s` rather than `%a` because you want to input as a string (IE `%s` is a string).

As indicated by in the comments by [megaing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8472976/megaing)